# Is there a right way to load Tab.Screen component dynamically

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm new to React Native. I have the following component where I use the function `useEffect`. However it is not being called.

What I want is to dynamically load the Tab.Screen component from API. I do this as follows in the code shown here below:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer, useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'

import HomeScreen from './src/screens/Home/HomeScreen'
import productTypeService from './src/services/ProductTypeService/ProductTypeService';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    productTypeService.getProductType()
      .then(result => {
        console.log("App -> result", result)
        setTabs(result.data.data)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        {tabs.map((tab) => (
          <Tab.Screen
            name={tab.description}
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'Home',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
              ),
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure `productTypeService.getProductType()` is not failing, add a catch to check. If it's going into the catch block the data won't be updated.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but I already checked this and it does not fail at all

Comment: What is the output of `console.log("App -> result", result)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `productTypeService.getProductType()` call correctly returns a result where `result.data.data` is a non empty array of objects. So `res.data.data` should return something like this:

```
[{description: "1"}, {description: "2"}]
```

You need to additionally add a check for when your array is empty as you can't return a navigator without screens. So you could do something like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  {tabs.length > 0 && (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      {tabs.map(tab => (
        <Tab.Screen
          name={tab.description}
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Here we don't render the navigator if there are no screens to render for that navigator.